# Unable to execute a substitute regex from inside a function

Tags: regular-expression, normal-mode

I have this function:

```
function! Insert_article()
  execute "normal! :r !insert_article.pl\<cr>"
  execute "normal! :%s/\v^(#+\s+[^\n#]+)\n([^#]*#+)/\1 \2/g\<cr>"
endfunction
```

The regex that is run works when run directly in the vim command line but chokes when called from inside function. I tried escaping the slashes but that didn't help.

Comment: Remove that execute/normal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this is failing for you is the backslashes inside the double quoted string. Your `\n` there will actually become a line break rather than a literal `\n`. Also the `\1` and `\2` will be interpreted by Vim as ASCII characters 0x01 and 0x02, which match `^A` (Ctrl-A) and `^B` (Ctrl-B) respectively.

If you were to escape those backslashes by doubling them with `\\` inside a double quoted string, that should work. You could also use a single quoted string (in which case backslashes don't introduce special characters), but then you would need something special for the `\<cr>` at the end where you're relying on the backslash behavior.

But there's a much simpler way!

First, you're using `:normal!` followed by a `:` to introduce an Ex command. While that works, the `:normal!` (which is an Ex command itself) is unnecessary here, since you can just execute Ex commands directly and both `:r` and `:%s` are Ex commands themselves. So you could easily simplify that to:

```
function! Insert_article()
  execute 'r !insert_article.pl'
  execute '%s/\v^(#+\s+[^\n#]+)\n([^#]*#+)/\1 \2/g'
endfunction
```

Note that this way you can get rid of the `\<cr>` at the end, so you can also move to single quotes, which solves the issue with the backslashes.

But you can simplify it further, since the main point of `:execute` is when you need to assemble the command from a string, but that's not really the case here, since you're just passing it constant strings. (There are other situations where you typically employ `:execute`, for instance to run multiple commands separated by `|`s when the commands don't take a `|` as a separator, but that's not the case here either.

So you can go all the way to:

```
function! Insert_article()
  r !insert_article.pl
  %s/\v^(#+\s+[^\n#]+)\n([^#]*#+)/\1 \2/g
endfunction
```

Pretty straightforward!